# Notes date filtration from db

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to filter data from the database by date, but I can't do it. As a result, only the Note for the month I need should be output.

I tried to do filtering, but I get an error:

```
Class 'Note' has no instance method '[]'. 
Receiver: Instance of 'Note' 
Tried calling: []("noteDate")
```

## NoteList class

```
final List _allNotes = [];
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _foundNotes = [];


  @override
  initState() {
    for (var note in notesModel.entityList) { _allNotes.add(note); }
    print('_allNotes = $_allNotes');
    // at the beginning, all users are shown
    _foundNotes = _allNotes.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    _runFilter(date.month);

    super.initState();
  }

  void _runFilter(date) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>>? results = [];
    print(date);
    print(_allNotes);
    if (date == null) {
      results = _allNotes.cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    } else {
      results = _allNotes
          .where((note) => note['noteDate'].contains(date)).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()
          .toList();
    }

    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _foundNotes = results!;
      print('## _runFilter setState() ${_foundNotes}');
    });
  }
```

## Note class:

```
class Note {
/// The fields this entity type contains.
int? id;
String? title;
String? content;
String? mood;
String? noteDate; // YYYY,MM,DD
String? noteTime; // HH,MM

/// Just for debugging, so we get something useful in the console.
String toString() {
return "{id: $id, title: $title, content: $content, color: $mood, noteDate: $noteDate, noteDate: $noteTime}";
}
}
```

Also, I can't get the notes data right away when I run the code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you confused how to access Dart objects with JS objects?

You're doing this:

`results = _allNotes.where((note) => note['noteDate'].contains(date)).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>()`

If you use Dart and want to access an object's property you must always use the dot notation, assuming `note` is of class `Note`:

`note.noteDate` works in Dart (and in JS)

`note['noteDate']` would work only in Dart if `note` is a map that had the key `noteDate`

`note['noteDate']` would work in JS

Your code fails because your class `Note` doesn't have any `[]` operator. Please see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List-class.html and see also https://dart.dev/language/operators

Try

```
_allNotes.where((note) => note.noteDate?.contains(data)).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried and i got new error: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Pattern' of 'pattern'. It indicates the beginning 'contains(date)'

Comment: You're using this method https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/String/contains.html on a String object. This means that `contains` only accepts an object of the type/interface `Pattern`. In Dart every string is a `Pattern`, so you can use a string as an argument. But your error msg tells that `date` is an integer. Try to convert it to a string with `toString()` method or check with `note.noteDate != null && note.Date == date` for equality.